# Награда за просмотр видео в игре Android

Tags: android, admob

Покажите на примере реализацию получения награды в игре за просмотр видеоролика от AdMob.

Comment: Тебе на http://fl.ru

Comment: Смотри в [комментах](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875158/adding-rewards-system-points-android)